# Validity of simple calculus result for Banach space-valued functions.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space and $x:[0,1]\to V$ a continuous function. Suppose further that $x(0) = 0$, $x\vert_{(0,1)}$ is continuously differentiable with derivative $\dot x$ and that $\lim_{t\to 0}\dot x(t)=0.$

Is this enough to deduce that $x(t)=\mathrm o(t)$ as $t\to 0$, i.e. $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{x(t)}{t}=0\;?$$

---

My attempted proof:
Assuming the fundamental theorem of calculus and Lebesgue differentiation theorem hold for Banach space-valued functions (recall $x(0)=0$), $$x(t) = \int_{0}^t\dot x(s)ds$$ and hence $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{x(t)}{t}=\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t\dot x(s)ds = \dot x(0) = 0.$$
I would greatly appreciate my attempted proof being critiqued!

Answer (score 0):

The Mean Value Theorem takes the form of an inequality for vector-valued functions. That is: if $f\colon [a,b]\to V$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that 
$$\|f(b)-f(a)\|\le \|f'(c)\| (b-a) \tag{1}$$
To prove this, let $\phi$ be any unit-norm functional on $V$ and apply the standard Mean Value Theorem to the scalar-valued function $\phi\circ f$. This yields 
$$|\phi(f(b)-f(a))| = |(\phi\circ f)'(c)| (b-a) \le \|f'(c)\| (b-a)\tag{2}$$
Taking the supremum over all such $\phi$ leads to (1).

The inequality (1) immediately yields the result you are looking for. You don't even need to assume the derivative to be continuous, nor to concern yourself with the integration of Banach space valued functions.